# Rabbit's nose lost from unknown cause

Tags: rabbits

[Injured Rabbit (Not for the squeamish!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAiv4.jpg)

Mouse over shows image.

> [image: Injured Rabbit]

Hello, I live in a village, and I found this rabbit outside my door this morning, it does not seem to have much power, I can hold it with minimum resistance. It suffers severe nose lost, the bones are visible. I was told by one of my one villagers that it is old and sick with psoriasis and it is common practice to release these animals to become prey of wild animals of the area.
I tried to feed it, it does not show interest, gave it water with siringue, it took some.

What disease does the animal seem to have?

How should it be given first aid?

There is no doctor available.

Thank you very much,

El

Comment: The image does appear to be of a domestic rabbit, This question is in scope here.

Comment: One of the most common issues with domestic rabbits that lead to similar symptoms is Fly Strike http://www.rabbit.org/journal/2-12/fly-strike.html I am not able to tell from the photo (which is very helpful) if this is the cause.  If you are able to discover the cause please post an answer to your question to benefit others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Take this rabbit straight to the vet. It will need an antibiotic to stop infection pain killers and an anti inflammatory. Try offering kale, romaine lettuce, carrot, banana, hay.Give water in a bowl as this does not look like a domestic rabbit. Also try making 'porridge'.

Mix 1 tsp of oats with some water until a porridge like mixture, you could try adding a bit of mashed banana to make it more appetising. Try not to introduce everything at once do the kale First and the oats. Watch his\hers droppings to check that they do not become too wet if so stop with the oats and banana.